# Problem with stardardization in R

Tags: r, scale-construction

I have dataframe: 
I try compute stardardization

```r
wine <- read.csv("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv", sep=";", colClasses = c('factor', 'factor', 'factor', 'factor', 'factor', 'numeric', 'numeric', 'factor', 'factor', 'factor', 'factor', 'numeric'))
wine[,1:12] <- apply(wine[,1:12], 2, function(x) x - mean(x))
wine[,1:12] <- apply(wine[,1:12], 2, function(x) x / sd(x))
```

second approach:

```r
scale(wine[,1:12])
```

result:

```
the few arguments submitted to the bi-argumental operator
```

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: Are all variables numeric? If not try using only numerical variables first.

Comment: Works for ```colClasses = c('numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric')```, why?

Comment: This seems to be a basic R question about the difference between factor variables and numeric variables. A variable registering whether a ball is blue, red or yellow can be coded 1,2,3. Then you can calculate the mean but this mean is statistically non-sensical. To prevent this from happening variables in R can be coded as being factors. Offcourse you can also take data that really is numerical and tell R to treat it as being a factor (categorial data) hence not allowing you to take the mean.

Comment: Anyways as long as you are asking purely about R functionality, this question is off-topic here and you should move it to stack overflow, here it will be closed and left unanswered (most likely).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of them are factor

```
 for(i in 1:12) {print(paste("columne i=",i,"is",class(wine[,i])) );flush.console()}
 [1] "columne i= 1 is factor"
 [1] "columne i= 2 is factor"
 [1] "columne i= 3 is factor"
 [1] "columne i= 4 is factor"
 [1] "columne i= 5 is factor"
 [1] "columne i= 6 is numeric"
 [1] "columne i= 7 is numeric"
 [1] "columne i= 8 is factor"
 [1] "columne i= 9 is factor"
 [1] "columne i= 10 is factor"
 [1] "columne i= 11 is factor"
 [1] "columne i= 12 is numeric"

 wine[,c(6,7,12)]
 std.wine<-apply(wine[,c(6,7,12)], 2, function(x) x - mean(x))
```

if you insist standarize factors! see [how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information) to convert them to numeric.

Use in following format

```
as.numeric(levels(f))[f]
```

where $f$ is the factor you want to convert to numeric. for example

```
> mean(wine[,1])
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(wine[, 1]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
> mean(as.numeric(levels(wine[,1]))[wine[,1]])
[1] 8.319637
```

Comment: hey, you cannot convert a factor to numeric and scale.. how would you interpret standard deviation and mean of factors?

Comment: @StupidWolf , first thank you, then, Yes you right, it means nothing to convert it, so I said "if you insist"!!! and after it I said "standardize factor !" with $!$ at end.